# Open folder from terminal using Forklift

Tags: terminal, finder, defaults

I'm often opening a folder from the terminal in Finder using `open .` or `open ./thisfolder`.

I just switched from Finder to Forklift, set it as default file viewer via `defaults write -g NSFileViewer -string com.binarynights.ForkLift-3` but folders still open in Finder.

How can I change that?